# Ruby ERB - Create a content_for method

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm currently working on an ERB View class for a gem. With this class I would like to have some helper methods for ERB templates.
It's okay about basic helpers like `h(string)`. I found [`erbh` gem](https://github.com/winebarrel/erbh) who help me to understand more how context works.
But now I'm trying to create a `content_for` method like there is in Rails or Sinatra.

On first time I was using simple `Proc` to capture the view block and then just calling `call` method to print it. It was working enough at the beginning.
But after having completed views I saw wired thinks, some content are printed multiple times.
So I take a look on the [Sinatra ContentFor helper](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/98990ef31f42ed00b8a7c0dae1170fe24e182612/sinatra-contrib/lib/sinatra/content_for.rb#L111) to understand how they did it and I copy some methods of this helper. I have no errors, but the block return are always empty... and I don't really know why.

My knowledge about ERB are not good enough to know how ERB buffering works.

### Code

Here a gist who explain the status of my code. I extracted the code from my library and simplified it a bit.

https://gist.github.com/nicolas-brousse/ac7f5454a1a45bae30c52dae826d587f/66cf76c97c35a02fc6bf4a3bc13d8d3b587356de

### What I would like?

I just would like to have `content_for` methods works like they do with Rails and Sinatra.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [blog article](http://brianwhitmer.blogspot.fr/2009/07/ruby-erb-and-outputbuffer.html) I finally found why it wasn't working. I don't know if I did it in the best way and cleaner way but it works.

So the bug was mainly from the `ERB` initilization. By using a property instead a local variable as [`eoutvar`](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-brousse/ac7f5454a1a45bae30c52dae826d587f/df9e9aa6d0522bb36c8969e86c46ebb92f121a70#file-view-rb-L53) it now works.

```rb
erb = ERB.new(str, nil, "<>", "@_erbout")
```

I also change a bit the `capture` method who is used by `content_for` helper.

It looks like this now ([gist](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-brousse/ac7f5454a1a45bae30c52dae826d587f/df9e9aa6d0522bb36c8969e86c46ebb92f121a70#file-view-rb-L110-L116))

```rb
def content_for(key, content = nil, &block)
  block ||= proc { |*| content }
  content_blocks[key.to_sym] << capture_later(&block)
end

def content_for?(key)
  content_blocks[key.to_sym].any?
end

def yield_content(key, default = nil)
  return default if content_blocks[key.to_sym].empty?
  content_blocks[key.to_sym].map { |b| capture(&b) }.join
end

def capture(&block)
  @capture = nil
  @_erbout, _buf_was = '', @_erbout
  result = yield
  @_erbout = _buf_was
  result.strip.empty? && @capture ? @capture : result
end

def capture_later(&block)
  proc { |*| @capture = capture(&block) }
end
```